# Java reading files from dynamic external jar

Tags: java, dynamic, external, urlclassloader

What i am trying to do and have been researching on how to do for many days is to have a mother jar that looks through a folder and loads all the jars in there dynamically ( Not really needing to know about them ) for this to work i need a file inside the plugins called `plugin`. I Currently have a working class loader that can start the plugins but i can not read the `plugin` file.

here is my current code:

**Load.class**

```
Load(JMenuBar Bar) {

ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        ClazzL = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("/home/grant/plugins/MenuPlugin.jar").toURL()}, currentThreadClassLoader);
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClazzL);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClazzL.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/menuplugin/plugin")));

        System.out.println("in: " + in.readLine());


        Class c = ClazzL.loadClass("menuplugin.Main");//this works and loads properly
                                                      //it is just that it needs to
                                                      //load from `plugin` using
                                                      //in.readLine();
        API obj = (API) c.newInstance();
        obj.run(Bar);

}
```

the error is (line 44: in = new Buffered....)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at menuaddon.Load.<init>(Load.java:42)
at menuaddon.Menuaddon.main(Menuaddon.java:39)
Java Result: 1
```

much help appreciated

the finished working code is:

```
ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        ClazzL = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("/home/grant/plugins/MenuPlugin.jar").toURL()}, currentThreadClassLoader);
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClazzL);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClazzL.getResourceAsStream("plugin")));
        classpath = in.readLine();
        Class c = ClazzL.loadClass(classpath);
        API obj = (API) c.newInstance();
        obj.run(Bar);
```

Comment: So what happens? Do you get `in` or not?

Comment: @Thilo in returns `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at menuaddon.Load.<init>(Load.java:42)
 at menuaddon.Menuaddon.main(Menuaddon.java:39)
Java Result: 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ClazzL` actually is a variable, and references the classloader, then try just

```
ClazzL.getResourceAsStream("/menuplugin/plugin")
```

instead. If you do `ClazzL.getClass().getClassLoader()`, you're trying to load the resource from the classloader of your `ClazzL` class, not the classloader you have created.

Comment: ClazzL.getResourceAsStream("/menuplugin/plugin") = null

Comment: Try it without the leading `/`. `ClazzL.getResourceAsStream("menuplugin/plugin")`

Comment: Strange. I have created an example just like yours, and it works just fine... Are you sure the file is within the jar with the name and path you're using?

Comment: what i had wrong was `plugin` was located at `/`  so what i should have had was `ClazzL.getResourceAsStream("plugin")`

Comment: thanks for the help now for certain something will go wrong again :)

Answer (score 2):

Get an URL of the plugin file using [getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), then open an input stream on it.

EDIT: You have to do it using a class that you've loaded using the URL classloader you created - **not the classloader's classloader as in your original example** - that only sees the classpath of parent classloader, not the one you've just created.

This code should work:

```
Class c = ClazzL.loadClass("menuplugin.Main");
URL pluginFileUrl = c.getResource("/menuplugin/plugin"); // This returns an URL representing resource on the classpath with a given file name.
InputStream inputStream = pluginFileUrl.openStream();
```

EDIT 2: NilsH's answer is of course a much more elegant shortcut.

Comment: That should work. The main difference being that you are now using the correct classloader (the one associated with the jar), not the system classloader.

Comment: Yes. I should explain myself better. Edited the answer.

Comment: the thing about this edit is that i need the file before i load the class... i am getting the main class of the plugin from the file

Comment: c.getResourceAsStream("menuplugin/plugin") = null

Comment: Ok, then NilsH's answer above should work for you, doesn't it?

Comment: so your saying that `c.getResourse()` should do it?

Comment: It should do the same as `getResource()` called on `ClassLoader` - i.e the same what others have suggested. If that won't work for you for some reason, then my answer probably won't work as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClazzL.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/menuplugin/plugin")
```

That is not loading from the classloader `ClazzL`, but from the class loader that defines URLClassLoader (i.e. the system classloader).

Try

```
ClazzL.getResourceAsStream("/menuplugin/plugin")
```

Comment: ClazzL.getResourceAsStream("/menuplugin/plugin") = null